# What are some synonyms for "mindbody" or "psychosomatic"?

Tags: synonyms, connotation, syllables

I'm open to synonyms for "mindbody" either as a noun (the combination of mind and body as one unit) or as an adjective (e.g. "psychosomatic" or "psychogenic").

But I can't have "psycho" in the term since that sometimes has unintended connotations.

And I'd prefer it to be only one or two syllables if possible.  If you can't think of any in English, non-English would also be interesting.  Thanks!

UPDATE: I should have more clearly stated that I'm trying to dumb down the language to make it as accessible and friendly as possible, so words like "somatization" are also not ideal.

Comment: Perhaps the sort of sentence you want to construct would be helpful....

Comment: "psychosomatic" is from "psychology". "psycho" is short for "psychotic".

Comment: I realize that "psycho" is short for "psychotic", but people's negative connotations expand beyond that.  Doctors find much resistance (at least in the US) when they try to inform patients of a psychosomatic diagnosis.  Many patients take offense and think that doctors are saying that the patients are lying or being manipulative (and that their pain or symptoms are imaginary or nonexistent).  I'm trying to introduce these concepts to people in a gentle, accessible way.  E.g. back pain and wrist pain are usually psychogenic (i.e. they are painful physical changes **induced by** the brain).

Comment: Context, please. I can't think of any situation in which both those words would be appropriate, and without context I have no idea which one you're trying to find an equivalent of. (And I think you're being oversensitive about "psycho". It's a perfectly legitimate root, and doesn't have negative connotations unless used in isolation.)

Comment: @Ryan Call it a "phantom" condition?

Comment: Yeah, that is a special challenge obviously.  If you can't think of it, it isn't likely to be very common or easily understood!  Good luck and I'll keep trying to think of something.  When this sort of thing does happen, common people would refer to it by some term implying mental problem, though.

Comment: @Ryan. I don't think of wrist pain as commonly being psychogenic.  I have this type discussion with people several times a week, however, and I try to explain the brain's critical role in interpreting pain from the extremities, which sometimes results in the sense of horrible damage to those extremities, though no horrible damage has occurred.  I often give examples like, "it feels broken" or "hit by a truck" though the individual knows better.  If you come up with a two syllable word that explains this clearly to people you will make my job loads easier!

Answer (score 1):

I would offer **holistic**.

> relating to or concerned with wholes or with complete systems rather
>   than with the analysis of, treatment of, or dissection into parts

Answer (score 1):

I usually use "somatized" (I don't like the "psych-" too), if it's the appropriate meaning you are searching for. I'm pretty sure it comes from latin "soma" which means body so it should work.

Comment: OED doesn't have *somatize* as a verb, but it does have *somatization:* "The occurrence of bodily symptoms in consequence of or as an expression of mental disorder." *Soma* is Greek, by the way. +1 though: this seems [to a non-medic] just what is needed.

Comment: Yeah, _somatization_ would be the term used by medical personal.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I've used "somatization" but have found that that requires lots of explanation, too.  I want to use words that are very accessible to a general population.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to think of a one or two syllable word -- nor of any existing synonym actually. But, how about such neologisms as "corpomentia" and "corpomential," "phrenosomatics" and "phrenosomatic," and "somatothymia" and "somatothymic?"